# C# Linq Left Outer Join WHERE clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a linq query where i'm trying to return data if the right `Sales` table doesn't have a record and also only if the `Sales.Fallthrough == false && Sales.Date == null`.

This is the base of my query and i've tried many different things with this but can't seem to get it to return the required data. Everything I try only seems to return records if there is no `Sales` OR they match the WERE caluse but not both.

```
from cr in efContext.Cases
join si in efContext.Sales on cr.CaseId equals si.CaseId into sicr
from sicr in (from si in sicr
                where si == null
                select si
                ).DefaultIfEmpty()
where cr.Withdrawn == false
    select new
    {
        CaseId = cr.CaseId,
        PropertyAddress = extension.PropertyAddressTownFormat(cr.PropertyAddress1, cr.PropertyTown),
        TargetExchangeDate = sicr.TargetExchangeDate == null ? null : sicr1.TargetExchangeDate,
        ActualExchangeDate = sicr.ActualExchangeDate,
    }).ToList();
```

**EDIT**
Missed out a little information.
Also if there is a record in `Sales` but does not match WHERE clauses then still return the left side and the right side as if there wasn't a record.

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen that and is what my query is based on but doesn't return the required data. I've edited the question as I missed a bit of info.

Comment: What do you mean by "Also if there is a record in Sales but does not match WHERE clauses"? Do you mean the query should return the join product if ``cr.Withdrawn == false``?

Comment: Sorry probably not explained it very well. So I need it to return all records from `Cases` if there is no record in `Sales`. If there is a record in `Sales` then filter for the `WHERE` clauses `Sales.Fallthrough == false && Sales.Date == null` But if it doesn't match the `WHERE` clauses then still return the record from `Cases`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just...?

```
from cr in efContext.Cases
join si in efContext.Sales on cr.CaseId equals si.CaseId into sicr
from s in sicr.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    CaseId = cr.CaseId,
    PropertyAddress = extension.PropertyAddressTownFormat(cr.PropertyAddress1, cr.PropertyTown),
    TargetExchangeDate = s == null || (s.Fallthrough == false && s.Date == null) ? null : s.TargetExchangeDate,
    ActualExchangeDate = s == null || (s.Fallthrough == false && s.Date == null) ? null : s.ActualExchangeDate,
};
```

Please note that you cannot call to ToList since the query returns an anonymous type.

Comment: I don't think this would return `Cases` where there is a `Sale` but don't match `s.Fallthrough == false && s.Date == null`

Comment: How about that then?